# Enforce constraint between two fields using the type system

Tags: typescript

I have a structure, `FashionVictim` with two fields that are not directly related. I want to introduce a constraint that all of its `clothes` have the same color as its `favoriteColor`.

```js
interface Cloth {
  color: Color;
  type: "T-shirt" | "Skirt" | "Pants";
}

interface FashionVictim {
  favoriteColor: Color;
  clothes: Cloth[];
}
```

I could express it in its constructor as a pre-condition

```js
constructor(favoriteColor: Color, clothes: Cloth[]) {
  // ...
  assert clothes.filter((c) => c.color != favoriteColor)).length == 0;
}
```

But that would check it only at runtime. I'm looking for a way to express it using a static type system, preferably in TypeScript. I'm also fine with using a function `getClothes()` instead of a field if it makes it easier.

Comment: It'll have to be generic, like this: https://tsplay.dev/w2264w

Answer (score 1):

First, let's say a `Cloth` can hold specific colors, not just `Color`. We can do this using generics:

```
interface Cloth<C extends Color = Color> {
    color: C;
    type: "T-shirt" | "Skirt" | "Pants";
}
```

I've also added a default so that using `Cloth` without passing any type parameters would behave the same as your original `Cloth` interface. Then, we can do the same with `FashionVictim`, to make sure that this victim only holds cloths with the same color:

```
interface FashionVictim<C extends Color = Color> {
    favoriteColor: C;
    clothes: Cloth<C>[];
}
```

Now, you can implement this interface using a generic class, passing on the type parameter:

```
class Fashionista<C extends Color> implements FashionVictim<C> {
    constructor(public favoriteColor: C, public clothes: Cloth<C>[]) {}
}
```

However, you'll notice that this is not quite right yet. This allows for invalid calls such as

```
new Fashionista("blue", [{ color: "green", type: "T-shirt" }]);  // okay...?
```

This because TypeScript infers `C` as `"blue" | "green"`. It's using both parameters as a point of inference, and is the subject of [ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829). One workaround would be to use a type that defers TypeScript's inference. There's many ways to do so, but here's my favorite:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

You would then wrap `C` with this type to block TypeScript from inferring types from the second parameter:

```
class Fashionista<C extends Color> implements FashionVictim<C> {
    constructor(public favoriteColor: C, public clothes: Cloth<NoInfer<C>>[]) {}
}
```

And now, it works!

```
new Fashionista("blue", [{ color: "blue", type: "Pants" }]);     // okay
new Fashionista("blue", [{ color: "green", type: "T-shirt" }]);  // error
new Fashionista("green", [{ color: "green", type: "T-shirt" }]); // okay
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigImRAJpqAHywHMcIA7A4zAIwQFcJqsAvAQwDNOdMBuAFACAlhWARkndgGNoMJMAAWAHhhQIAD3EVcAZ1iIU6A0mQA+KAG8BUW1GmHkALliC7UUJBeYAKgFpdRWFkYBZMAGUAa2DQoiwABXYxXX4BAF8hUXFJGWgAMXZA4TgKADVhaWBhAFtVdS1KPRMjDHhTC2t3KQA3FGFxNpQXGDc7aQVFCF1hidUzAG0AXUEMgU9oADk4AEkKTgllHwsMeZ9F0-rtJqSQKAB+KAAGKBcKCG6JZaFxwv0CopKwl0wHYdU0V30g3MUBqYAQEGqlGAf0KQRK5UqNTmVhsYxKwOQDEqKAAFGAGPQKlAen0Bo5hgAaKDkynSewTKYzOBKZRbXb7ZBzBaLACUVgyqzeAHcoP80RQgSCSXRGMwmfNLPZ6Vh6ExMEz1t5EskCGlRXx3FAAPRWqBwSLsEACaWy1HFBXA9jK3VqqAarWmbxkCCUfUecAQbz+IohU3m2w29TIZAoZ0QGVy92Kr2YYOh9WahyB0jkKgGiNRgJBWNQM0ii2J+2OgRAA)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the objective is when constructing a `FashionVictim`, you want to ensure that each `clothes.color` matches the value of the `favoriteColor` property, thus, ensuring the correct usage of your class.

For this reason, your class must have a generic type, lets call it `Color` and this color must extend from one of the allowed colors and only one.

You can use classes as units for each specific color with a unique value, ensuring that generic `Color` type cannot extend from two classes at the same time.

```
class Red {
  readonly value = 'red' as const
}

class Blue {
  readonly value = 'blue' as const;
}
```

*the `as const` tells typescript to treat the value as a literal and not as a string, thus `Red.value !== Blue.value`*

Now we can declare a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) between all the available colors. Not really needed in our example, but might help you further organizing your code and related business logic around the `Color` type

```
type Colors = Red | Blue;
```

We'll add a generic `Color` on the  `Cloth` interface that extends the `Colors` type and is assigned as the type of the `color` property

```
interface Cloth<Color extends Colors> {
  color: Color;
  type: "T-shirt" | "Skirt" | "Pants";
}
```

Now when we declare the **FashionVictim** class with the same `Color` generic that extends `Colors`, it will ensure that the constructor is used properly, ensuring the business rules ( each `chothes.color === favoriteColor`) at compile time.

```
class FashionVictim<Color extends Colors> {
  favoriteColor: Color;
  clothes: Array<Cloth<Color>>;

  constructor(favoriteColor: Color, clothes: Cloth<Color>[]) {
    this.favoriteColor = favoriteColor;
    this.clothes = clothes;
  }
}
```

TS Tests:

```
const test1 = new FashionVictim(new Red(), [{color: new Blue(), type: 'Skirt'}]); // TS: Type 'Blue' is not assignable to type 'Red'.

const test2 = new FashionVictim(new Blue(), [{color: new Blue(), type: "Pants"}]); // no compiler errors 

test2.clothes.push({color: new Red(), type: "Pants"}); // TS: Type 'Red' is not assignable to type 'Blue'
test2.clothes.push({color: new Blue(), type: "Pants"}); // No compiler error
```

This cannot work with a union of string literals, as described above by [vr.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75860280) because the type of `'red'|'blue'` is ether `'red'` or `'blue'` and both of them extends from primitive `string`. However, on my example, generic `Color` cannot extend from both `Red` and `Blue` classes at the same time.

[Typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEBKBTAJrA3sWsBOiLIHsA7MAT1gDcIwBXRWAXlgHJdlnZpYRioAXYAF9goSDFgAhWvQxZc+YmUrU6jFgCNpHLjyL8A3EJF9SAB3oBhAmALY4TJKgA+k6YeABLIn0TYAZhAgljZ8ABYAPFY22LCIAB4+RMhwUbZQAHzomNzWtgBcsKnYhlgm5gUARAAqALRQoR7YfBWwLhUAygDWjc2tsBUAChDeUBWGwiLg0HAAYtANxABqHiB8HgC2kbkx8YnJhdsZWVgBFLYePkUFRSXcIaGIUAUAgtjYEKSR91vR6enuWF0-GwNFWtgAFKdzpdttdtgAaO4EMKPa7fIrpADaAF0AJTHLCwMIeKAAOih2AuiCKagpVJu2VKDTJ4GRD3sSJRUFuwgmQL4RMefAAjGoiIgAO6wOb1DxLFZrdbg8VSxzg3GIzFoHjRAoq1x0dWIsqIArMLo9ZiCPGGfmC-gAJjFkul8zlRGWqw2ypdUkNGtgWp1+Vg+r9iCNRLMpv6QxGFWtuPcPkdpNZXNJpho9XB2thoZdaoDJsqcb4o0ESeAKb4DrT90emezoVzwewet90kjJdjw3LCaroF41kQpJsAHNwTXhUmgA)